# How to check user's permission before moving a file to a different machine?

Tags: c#, permissions, io

I want to move/copy a file into a folder on a different machine, and I want to check if the user has sufficient permissions to do this. How can I do this, where do I start? Is it even possible in C#?

Answer (score 1):

There is `System.Security.FileIOPermission`-class that exposes methods to check on permissions.

Example from MSDN

```
FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "C:\\test_r");
f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "C:\\example\\out.txt");
try
{
    f2.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
}
```

You pass a file/directory to the constructor and add additional files/directories using `AddPathList`. Then you check if access can be granted using `Demand()`-method. If the caller has insufficient rights, a `SecurityException` is thrown.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx).

Comment: isn't this to check for permission to write into a file ?, i want to move the file from one path to another path , so want to check if i have the permission to write into that particular directory.

Comment: This is why you specify the permissions using the `FileIOPermissionAccess`-enumeration. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check article on code project which is about the thing you need

[access rights for a given file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14402/Testing-File-Access-Rights-in-NET-2-0)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to check for permission to Move the file to a particular directory ... not to write into a file  ..can u suggest any other method